# AngularJS $http returns status code 0 and data as null in SharePoint 2013

Tags: angularjs, http, sharepoint-2013, single-page-application, office365-restapi

I am facing an issue when inserting records in to multiple lists using rest api with http calls in SharePoint 2013.

I have written common method mentioned below which will take input params as data and url.

```
  var postRequest = function (data, url) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http({
                    url: baseUrl + url,
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                        "If-Match": "*"
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify(data)
                }).success(function (result) {
                    alert(result.d.Id);
                    deferred.resolve(result.d.Id);
                }).error(function (result, status) {
                    alert(status + result);
                    deferred.reject(status);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            };
```

Using the above code I am inserting data in to list A, once record has been inserted in to list a, With item id of I am inserting record in list b with additional fields and list C.

I am calling above common method which is mentioned as below.

```
$scope.submitData = function (LSSDeal, lssIds, amIds) {
            var submitDataPromise = lssDealService.submitLSS(LSSDeal, lssIds, amIds);
            submitDataPromise.then(function (transactionResponse) {
                var transactionId = transactionResponse;
                $scope.AddtoPaymentList(LSSDeal, transactionId);
                $scope.AddToHistory(LSSDeal, transactionId);

            }, function (error) {
                alert("error in submitting transaction data" + error);
            });
        };
```

I am able to get transaction id for first request which will insert record in list A.After getting ID I am calling remaining two methods.

```
 $scope.AddtoPaymentList = function (LSSDeal, transactionId) {
                var paymentlistPromise = lssDealService.saveToPaymentList(LSSDeal, transactionId);
                paymentlistPromise.then(function (paymentlistResponse) {
                    var paymentId = paymentlistResponse;
                    alert("LSS Deal has been Added to payment list with transaction Id:" + transactionId);
                }, function (error) {
                    alert("error in inserting payment list data" + error);
                });
            };        
            $scope.AddToHistory = function (LSSDeal, parentListId) {
                var historyPromise = lssDealService.saveToHistory(LSSDeal, parentListId);
                historyPromise.then(function (historyResponse) {
                    var historyId = historyResponse;
                    alert("LSS Deal has been Added to history with history Id:" + historyResponse);

                }, function (error) {
                    alert("error in inserting history data" + error);
                });

            };
```

For remaining two methods I am always getting error message as status zero and data null.

Simply for second request on wards its going error block but records are inserting successfully.

But when I am debugging getting success messages. Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

References: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1002526/SharePoint-and-Angularjs